# Tangent space of a submanifold vs tangent space of an open set in a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. I learned that if $U$ is an open set in $M$ then the tangent spaces of $U$ are equal to the tangent spaces of $M$ at every point. On the other hand, if $N$ is a submanifold of $M$ then a tangent space of $M$ may not be the same as a tangent space of $N$. I'm confused in why this is true even though a submanifold of $M$ is an open set in it. (I apologize if my question is very stupid ).

Comment: In general, submanifold as a subset is not open. Think of the $x$-axis in $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: If $N \subset M$ is a submanifold and $x\in N$, then $T_xN$ is naturally a subspace of $T_xM$, with dimension $\dim N \leqslant \dim M$. If $N=U$ is open, then $T_xU$ is a linear subspace of $T_xM$ of the same dimension, hence is equal to $T_xM$.

Comment: Well I was always believing that a submanifold is an open set in the given  manifod! Many thanks to both of you Arctic Char and Didier for your comments.